# Что будет с результатом выполнения метода без присваивания?

Tags: java, сборщик-мусора, filestream, bytearray

Возник интересный вопрос. Можно даже сказать, вопрос из тех, которые возникают в голове часа в 3 ночи.) К сожалению, я не знаю, как его сформулировать, чтобы спросить у гугла.)

Есть свой вот такой вот метод:

```
    private byte[] takeBlobFromFile() throws IOException {
        String scriptTxt = "C:\\Tool\\blobText.txt";
        File file = new File(scriptText);
        byte[] fileContent = new byte[(int) file.length()];

        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file)) {
            fis.read(fileContent);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return fileContent;
    }
```

В нем мы читаем файл с длинным текстом (2500+ строк), после чего заполняем byte[] массив через FileInputStream. Нужно это для того, чтоб в дальнейшем передать этот массив в Blob для записи в соответствующее поле в базу данных.

И у меня IDEA ругается на метод fis.read(fileContent), говоря "Result of method call ignored".
Насколько я понял, имеется ввиду, что "Вы игнорируете результат выполнения метода", ведь он возвращает Int число записанных в массив байтов, а я его никуда не присваиваю. И вот это число-то мне как-бы и не нужно, и даже пусть висит этот варн.

Но стало интересно, а что будет фактически с этим результатом? Он будет удален сборщиком мусора сразу, как только завершится метод? Или даже не будет создан? Или создаст значение, но без ссылки в итоге удалит после окончания работы метода?

Comment: Как в книге написано: он будет создан. И будет удален сборщиком мусора. Но в какой момент это произойдет - неизвестно и предсказать невозможно.

Comment: такие вещи могут быть компилятором зарезаны. я про то, что у компилятора есть оптимизации при которых вызовы без побочного эффекта могут быть проигнорированы.

Comment: @МихаилРебров т.е., как я понимаю, лучше подобное куда-то присваивать, дабы избежать неявных проблем?

Comment: Метод `fis.read` не обязан считывать весь файл в один приём. Для больших файлов вероятна ситуация что будет прочитаны не все данные. Так что надо проверить сколько было прочитано байт. Если прочитано меньше чем вы ожидаете, данные надо будет дочитать методом [read(byte\[\] b, int off, int len)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read(byte[],%20int,%20int)). Дочитывать нужно тоже в цикле.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Спасибо за ответ!
Я правильно понимаю, что будет правильным сравнить результат `fis.read` с длинной файла `file.lenght`?

Comment: В вашем случае да.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Еще раз большое спасибо!

Comment: Для достаточно большого файла результат `(int) file.length()` может быть отрицательным, и не получится создать массив.

Comment: @NowhereMan Насколько я понимаю, у джавы "достаточно большой файл" в данном случае - 2Гб.. 
Что в случае с .тхт весьма огромный файлик.)
или я все же неверно сопоставляю число, возвращаемое методом lenght() с действительным размером файла?